# Composer autoload_namespaces array is empty, but it is downloading my packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using composer on windows, and it is successfully loading my 2 packages that I'm using from my composer.json file when I perform a `composer install` or `composer update`.

```
{
    "require": {
        "bcosca/fatfree": "dev-master",
        "respect/validation": "^1.1"
    }
}
```

The first line in my index.php is

```
require_once __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';
```

This didn't seem to be loading anything, a lot of errors related to classes not defined from these 2 packages, for example.  I looked into it further and discovered that my `autoload_namespaces.php` is as follows:

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
);
```

The array is completely empty, how does this happen?  I expected to see these 2 packages' requirements in here...

Thanks for the help!

Adding composer.json from the packages themselves:
F3:

```
{
    "name": "bcosca/fatfree",
    "description": "A powerful yet easy-to-use PHP micro-framework designed to help you build dynamic and robust Web applications - fast!",
    "homepage": "http://fatfreeframework.com/",
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.6"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["lib/base.php"]
    }
}
```

Validator:

```
{
    "name": "respect/validation",
    "description": "The most awesome validation engine ever created for PHP",
    "keywords": ["respect", "validation", "validator"],
    "type": "library",
    "homepage": "http://respect.github.io/Validation/",
    "license": "BSD Style",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Respect/Validation Contributors",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/Respect/Validation/graphs/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "egulias/email-validator": "~1.2",
        "malkusch/bav": "~1.0",
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "^1.5",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.6.9",
        "zendframework/zend-validator": "~2.3"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-bcmath": "Arbitrary Precision Mathematics",
        "ext-mbstring": "Multibyte String Functions",
        "egulias/email-validator": "Strict (RFC compliant) email validation",
        "malkusch/bav": "German bank account validation",
        "symfony/validator": "Use Symfony validator through Respect\\Validation",
        "zendframework/zend-validator": "Use Zend Framework validator through Respect\\Validation",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "Fix PSR2 and other coding style issues"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Respect\\Validation\\": "library/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Respect\\Validation\\": "tests/library/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.1-dev"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "./vendor/bin/phpunit"
    }
}
```

And after loading Validator, this Symfony component came with it:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/polyfill-mbstring",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension",
    "keywords": ["polyfill", "shim", "compatibility", "portable", "mbstring"],
    "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nicolas Grekas",
            "email": "p@tchwork.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Symfony Community",
            "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Symfony\\Polyfill\\Mbstring\\": "" },
        "files": [ "bootstrap.php" ]
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-mbstring": "For best performance"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the `composer.json` files of your packages. Without knowing how you configured autoloading for them we can only guess what's going wrong.

Comment: @xabbuh Sorry about that, they have been added now.

Comment: What sort of errors did you receive? `autoload_namespaces.php` should be empty as it is, since none of those dependencies use PSR-0 autoloading. Instead `autoload_files.php` and `autoload_psr4.php` contains information about your packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The array is completely empty, how does this happen? I expected to see these 2 packages' requirements in here...

- Composer supports multiple class loading methods. One important implements the `PSR4` specification. `Symfony` and `Respect` are using `PSR4`. You can verify it by looking at their `composer.json` files or your generated `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` file.
- Fat-Free Framework lets Composer *autoload* its `lib/base.php` file. This is important to know because including `base.php` twice will throw a `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Cache, because the name is already in use`. The solution is to let Composer do its job and fetch the `$f3 = Base::instance()` instead.

**Suggestions**

- Delete the `vendor` folder and make a clean install with `Composer`
- Verify that the class namespaces aren't missing (or are imported) in your code, e.g. `\Respect\Validation\Validator` instead of `Validator`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your require_once() line. It has not given the correct file path to the autoload.php. If your 'vendor' directory is in the same level as index.php then all you have to do is simply require the autoloader as shown below:

[image]

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo 'Loaded...';
```

Note that there is absolutely nothing wrong with the autoload_namespaces.php. Mine is also same as yours.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem as `require` and `require_once` produce a fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR` level error and halt the script instead of reporting unknown class names.

Comment: @Rayne agreed. Seems the require path is okay as well.